# diagrams.sty can't draw \ruTo(4,2)

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I ran into a problem of drawing an arrow `\ruTo(4,2)`. The following example didn't draw the diagonal arrow, as in

[image: ruTo]

However, it works well for `\rdTo(4,2)` and `\ruTo(2,2)`, as in

[image: rdTo]

and

[image: ruto2]

I'm really confused and would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[small,nohug,heads=LaTeX]{diagrams}
\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}
    a&\rTo&a&\rTo&a\\
    \dTo&\ruTo(4,2)&&&\dTo\\
    a&\rTo&a&\rTo&a
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you tied to `diagrams`?

Comment: I think I found a solution to my problem by replacing the second line of the diagram with \dTo&&&\ruTo(4,2)&\dTo\\

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because teh OP commented "problem solved", long ago.

Comment: Voting to reopen, closing a question as "solved in comments" is not a good idea, see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8778/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz -- Please also post a brief answer based on the comment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Will post a community wiki answer as soon as the question is reopened

Answer (score 1):

[As commented by the OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461772/diagrams-sty-cant-draw-ruto4-2?noredirect=1#comment1161780_461772), the problem can be solved by using `\dTo&&&\ruTo(4,2)&\dTo\\`

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[small,nohug,heads=LaTeX]{diagrams}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1\endgraf\unskip#2\foo{\def\row@to@buffer{#1\endgraf\unskip\unskip#2}}
\expandafter\foo\row@to@buffer\foo
\makeatother

\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}
    a&\rTo&a&\rTo&a\\
    \dTo&&&\ruTo(4,2)&\dTo\\ 
    a&\rTo&a&\rTo&a
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some useful hints how to get the `diagrams` package and compile documents using the package can be found in these answers:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660929/36296
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682489/36296