# Paul Taylor's diagrams.sty NEVER HAPPEN error redux

Tags: commutative-diagrams

This is essentially the same problem as in [Paul Taylor's diagrams.sty NEVER HAPPEN error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660920/paul-taylors-diagrams-sty-never-happen-error/660929) but the solution given there isn't working for me.

I previously had no problem with this on my old HP laptop running Windows 10, but I just got a new Dell with Windows 11. I installed `MiKTeX` (current version appears to be 22.10) and TeXstudio as I usually do. Now if I run the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
A & \rTo & B
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

I get an error that reads "Commutative Diagram: * THIS (S) SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN! * at lines 5--7 [1", although the TeXing finishes and the output pdf file seems to show the correct diagram.

I tried to implement the solution from the link above, but when I insert that code, I get the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\foo\row@to@buffer

Any suggestions for fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version, 3.96? Once I downloaded it from the author's homepage, your MWE compiled without issues with TL 2023 (Linux).

Comment: the version on ctan (3.93) is time bombed and does not work at all, use 3.96 from https://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/ save V3,96.tex as  diagrams.sty

Comment: Do remember to read the copyright statement in the file, especially the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version on ctan (3.93) is time bombed and does not work at all, use 3.96 from http://paultaylor.eu/diagrams save `V3,96.tex` as `diagrams.sty` then the adjustment at [Paul Taylor's diagrams.sty NEVER HAPPEN error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660920/paul-taylors-diagrams-sty-never-happen-error/660929) should work.